# Handling callback in recursive asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, html, recursion, callback, jaydata

I am using Jaydata as API for HTML5 indexedDB. I have a table in indexedDB where I need to query recursively. I need a callback when entire process is completed. Following is the recursive function. I need to have a callback when everything is done.

```
function getData(idValue) {
    myDB.MySplDB
        .filter( function(val) {
            return val.ParentId == this.parentId;
        }, {parentId: idvalue})
        .toArray( function(vals) {
            if(vals.length < 1) {
                // some operation to store the value
            } else {
                for (var j=0;j<vals.length;j++) {
                    getData(vals[j].Id);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Adding `.done(function(){...});` to `.toArray` doesn't work since it gets called before completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I work for JayData)

To wait for the finish of the entire process you need to use promises. You always have to return a promise. In the loop it gets tricky, return a super promise. So the code should be something like this:

```
function getData(idValue) {
    return myDB.MySplDB
    .filter( function(val) {
        return val.ParentId == this.parentId;
    }, {parentId: idvalue})
    .toArray( function(vals) {
        if(vals.length < 1) {
            // some operation to store the value
            // important: return a promise from here, like:
            return myDB.saveChanges(); 
        } else {
            var promises = [];
            for (var j=0;j<vals.length;j++) {
                promises.push(getData(vals[j].Id));
            }
            return $.when.apply(this, promises);
        }
    });
}

getData(1)
.then(function() {
        // this will run after everything is finished
});
```

remarks:

1. this example uses jQuery promises, so you'll need jQuery 1.8+
   $.when uses varargs hence we need the apply
2. this can work with q promise with a slightly different syntax

Comment: In the section `// some operation to store the value`, I m not storing the value in the DB. I am storing these in an array. The intention is to get all the elements which does not have children i.e. the Id of the object is not parentId of any other object.

Comment: What else must I return instead of `return myDB.saveChanges(); ` if I am not storing the value in DB ?

Comment: In that case you can return anything, like return true;

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain about the section `var promises = [];
            for (var j=0;j<vals.length;j++) {
                promises.push(getData(vals[j].Id));
            }
            return $.when.apply(this, promises);`

Comment: It collects promises and return a promise which gets resolved when all promise in the array resolved

Comment: The above code isn't working. `.then(function{..})` is getting called before itself.

Comment: ok, I never use callback functions but I wanted to change your code as little as possible so I left your callback function in place but callback can not return a promise. Also the free indexeddb provider does not like to be called in recursive parallel manner, so I rewrite that part to build a promise chain. You can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/JayData/vsxZT/

Comment: Could you please explain `var promise = getData(vals.shift().Id);
            for (var j=0;j<vals.length;j++) {
                promise = promise.then(function(){ return getData(vals.shift().Id) });
            }
            return promise;` section of the code ?

Comment: it builds a chain of promise, a sequence, when the first promise is resolved then the next one is executed, the last promise resolves the whole chain

Comment: So the purpose is to queue up promises ? Can we queue up promises by appending .then() next to it. i.e. promise.then(..).then(..) ?

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. I have marked as answer and voted for the appropriate answer in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Would this pseudo-code make sense in your case ?

```
var helper = function (accu) {
 // Take an id from the accumulator
 // query the db for new ids, and in the db query callback : 
   // If there is child, do "some operation to store the value" (I'm not sure what you're trying to do here
   // Else add the child to the accumulator
   // if accu is empty, call the callback, it means you reached the end
```

getData() would call this helper with an accumulator containing the first id, and your final callback